# How to show events are "asymptotically independent"

Tags: probability

Recently [A problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836821/what-s-the-probability-for-this-problem) in this site asked: shuffling a class of students sitting in pairs - what is the probability that at least one pair "survives". I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4836960/168323) by leonbloy, which provides very elegant way for approximating (for a large number of students) a rather computationally-difficult probability question. The answer states that: "We can expect that the events $E_i \equiv$ "the pair $i$ survived", are asymptotically independent".

I can clearly see that any given pair of events like $E_z$, $E_y$ is asymptotically independent; but initially, it does not seem immediately trivial to me that they are asymptotically fully/manually independent in the sense that would allow the approximation to work. In fact, strictly speaking, they are *not* fully independent since the "last" pair is determined by all the previous ones: though I understand this is marginal case and should not have an impact on the result. But what if we fix half of the pairs: can we say the second half is not "influenced"/dependent by this? Well, I guess we can at infinity - but how to show it technically? How to show that we can use this approximation method?